# how to access Couchbase server (on windows 7) by a remote app .net

Tags: .net, networking, couchbase

i have installed couchbase server on windows 7.
i created a small c# .net app which communicate with it, on my local machine.
i am trying to create an app that would do just that but from a remote computer.
(connect to the couchbase on my computer from a remote computer)
in app.config i add
//add uri="http://192.168.0.100:8091/pools"/
im behind a router (big difference?)
what do i need to change or do, to be able to connect from a remote pc?
answers or links will be appreciated, including anything that might help.

- i could not find tutorials on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the change to the URI in the app.config is needed.  Well, you may also need to make sure any firewalls (or other network config) allow the new client to contact the server on ports 8091, 8092 and 11210 as well.  See the docs on couchbase.com/docs for details on what network ports may need to be open if you have multiple couchbase servers, etc.  That's it.

Comment: Yes this is correct! i had a problem that the couchbase server would assign local ip's and then the clients could not reach them. solution is here:http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/issues-dhcp-development-laptop