# Couchbase on remote machine is not accessable

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

I have installed couchbase (windows v2.1.1) on my 2 laptops. I see both of the them are up and everything in admin page seems to be ok. But there is a bizarre issue. .NET client works perfectly fine on of the laptops, the one I have installed the first server, but does not work on the other. I have tried to use IPs, machine names (as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317188/how-to-access-couchbase-server-on-windows-7-by-a-remote-app-net)) in app.config nothing helps. I also have firewall disabled. It works only if I set 127.0.0.1 in app.config.

**UPDATE**
Also when one of the nodes goes down all the data on that node becomes unavailable.

Comment: Can you provide more info about what ips or dns names (with their ips)  that couchbase uses (you can see them in admin console)? And to make it work you need exactly same ips or dns names in app.config and in admin console. I think you've got the same problem as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682658/insert-into-remote-couchbase-server-by-python/19687027)

Comment: @m03geek I have tried all options. I have used the same IPs as shown in admin console. Still no success.

Comment: Let's try to localize problem. Can you answer some questions: 1) Are those laptops in LAN or they are connected through internet? 2) Have you joined them in one cluster, or not? 3) Maybe ip of someone node has canged after setup? 4) Does IPs of `couchApiBase` that you can see at http://<couchbase's ip>:8091/pools/default match IPs in admin console and in your app? 5) Can you provide your app config couchbase section? 6) IPs of which network adapter (wifi/eth) couchbase took after setup?

You can update your question with answers to these questions. I think this info will be useful.